# Problems using Matlab Builder JA

Tags: java, matlab, compiler-errors, matlab-deployment

First of all I would like to thank in advance everyone for reading such a long post. I really appreciate your help.

The thing is that I've been doing some research on how to "connect" Matlab and Java for a project I am working on for university. I figured that the most suitable option was using Matlab Builder JA, but I'm having a lot of troubles with it.

I follow step by step the instructions described on a tutorial (the link of the video in below) but get compilation errors over and over, and I really don't know how to fix them. The tutorial is about creating a Java package (demo.jar) with MATLAB ("com.demo"), which contains a class (MLTestClass) with a function `makeSqr(n)` which returns an n × n square matrix. Then I go to Eclipse, I add to the project both libraries javabuilder.jar and demo.jar and then create the following class:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        MLTestClass x = null;
        Object result [] = null;

        try {
            x = new MLTestClass ();
            result = x.makeSqr (1, 5);
            System.out.println (result [0]);
        } catch (MWException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Of course I import com.demo.* and com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.*.

Here are the errors the console gives me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration.getProxyLibraryDir(MCRConfiguration.java:163)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$MCRRoot.get(MCRConfiguration.java:77)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$MCRRoot.<clinit>(MCRConfiguration.java:87)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration.getMCRRoot(MCRConfiguration.java:92)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$ModuleDir.<clinit>(MCRConfiguration.java:66)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration.getModuleDir(MCRConfiguration.java:71)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.<clinit>(MWMCR.java:1573)
    at com.demo.DemoMCRFactory.(DemoMCRFactory.java:122)
    at com.demo.MLTestClass.(MLTestClass.java:63)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$ProxyLibraryDir.get(MCRConfiguration.java:143)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$ProxyLibraryDir.<clinit>(MCRConfiguration.java:158)
    ... 10 more
```

Just in case, link tutorial (it's the video): http://www.mathworks.nl/products/javabuilder/description2.html

Anyone has any ideas what the problem could be? It says something about NullPointerException, but I don't know how to solve it as the constructor is provided by the class created with MATLAB. I didn't have any issues installing MCR, and by the way I have MacOS, which I hope is not the source of the problem :).

Again, sorry for the long post and thank you for your time.

Béntor.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, please install MCR. The installation also mentions about setting environmental variables like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` etc. If you are using eclipse, i would recommend you update the environmental variables

- right click->
- properties ->
- run/debug settings->
- environmental variables

I also had to make sure that variable `MCR_CACHE_ROOT` pointed to different directory since my home directory was not big enough.

Answer (score 1):

You have install MCR (avaliable in http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions helped me (I already had MCR installed and Macs use DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH instead of LD_LIBRARY_PATH), and noone else online seemed to know. Finally in desperation, I tried editing the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and finally got it to work by removing the last part of it: /Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v82/sys/java/jre/maci64/jre/lib

Now the demo application from the tutorial works.

Next comes trying to make my code work.

Answer (score 0):

OS X Paths for Run-Time Deployment

Use these setenv commands to set your MATLAB Runtime paths.

```
setenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH \
       mcr_root/version/runtime/maci64 \
       mcr_root/version/bin/maci64 \
       mcr_root/version/sys/os/maci64
```

Source: http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/java/mcr-path-settings-for-run-time-deployment.html